# Why aren't generator expressions evaluated for LINK_LIBRARIES?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I want to dump various CMake target properties to a file. These properties can contain generator expressions, which I expect to be resolved to actual values. This can be done with `file(GENERATE)` command.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(Test)

add_executable(Exec main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Exec PRIVATE Lib0 $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Lib1,Lib2>)
target_include_directories(Exec PRIVATE /Dir0 $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,/Dir1,/Dir2>)
target_compile_definitions(Exec PRIVATE -DVALUE=Val0 -DVALUE=$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Val1,Val2>)
target_compile_options(Exec PRIVATE Opt0 $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Opt1,Opt2>)

set(EXPR "\
$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Exec,LINK_LIBRARIES>
$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Exec,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Exec,COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>
$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Exec,COMPILE_OPTIONS>
")
file(GENERATE OUTPUT output$<CONFIG>.txt CONTENT "${EXPR}")
```

This works great for all properties I tried except for `LINK_LIBRARIES` - generator expressions are not resolved. See output for debug config:

```
Lib0;$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Lib1,Lib2>
/Dir0;/Dir1
VALUE=Val0;VALUE=Val1
Opt0;Opt1
```

Can this be fixed somehow? Is this behavior documented?

Comment: Which generator is used?

Comment: @273K I tried Makefiles GCC on Linux and MSVC on Windows. Same results.

Answer (score -1):

Generator expressions in `LINK_LIBRARIES` aren't directly evaluated because `LINK_LIBRARIES` is a more complex property that handles both direct and transitive dependencies. CMake defers the resolution of generator expressions in this context to the generation phase to ensure all dependencies are known.

To get the evaluated link libraries, you should use the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property instead:

```
$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Exec,INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES>
```

Comment: "you should use the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property instead" - But these properties have **different meaning**: `LINK_LIBRARIES` contains libraries which will be linked to the **target** itself, but `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` contains libraries which will be linked to **users** of that target. In other words, the property `LINK_LIBRARIES` contains libraries specified with PRIVATE or PUBLIC keywords in `target_link_libraries` call, but `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property is filled with INTERFACE or PUBLIC keywords.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Agree, `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` is a completely different property. Also, generator expressions are not expanded either  - same as `LINK_LIBRARIES`.